# Regex replace only matching groups and ignore non-matching groups?

Tags: c#, regex

Regex.Replace says :

> In a specified input string, replaces all strings that match a
>   specified regular expression with a specified replacement string.

In my case:

```
string w_name = "0x010102_default_prg_L2_E2_LDep1_LLC";
string regex_exp = @"(?:E\d)([\w\d_]+)(?:_LLC)";
w_name = Regex.Replace(w_name, regex_exp, string.Empty);
```

Output:

```
0x010102_default_prg_L2_
```

but I was expecting

```
0x010102_default_prg_L2_E2_LLC
```

Why is it replacing my non-matching groups(group 1 and 3)? And how do I fix this in order to get the expected output?

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iX2xC1/1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn the first and last non-capturing groups to capturing groups so that you could refer thoses chars in the replacement part and remove the unnecessary second capturing group.

```
string w_name = "0x010102_default_prg_L2_E2_LDep1_LLC";
string regex_exp = @"(E\d)[\w\d_]+(_LLC)";
w_name = Regex.Replace(w_name, regex_exp, "$1$2");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mN7oE5/1)

or

```
string regex_exp = @"(?<=E\d)[\w\d_]+(?=_LLC)";
w_name = Regex.Replace(w_name, regex_exp, string.Empty);
```

Comment: This works: pls fix group selection from "$1$2" to "$1$3". Can you explain how it works? What if I needed to replace with say string "abc" instead of empty string?

Comment: @greenfeet why I need to change `$1$2` to `$1$3`, since I removed the second cap group present in your regex. 2. Just add `abc` inbetween `$1` and `$2` , ie `$1abc$2`. For the second answer, just `"abc"` instead of `string.Empty` would be enough.

Comment: you're right, I didn't notice you removed the second group, thanks!